# How do I put a specific row number from a MySQL table written into a HTML table, into a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I apologize if I'm wording this wrong, or asking a completely different question. To be honest, I have no idea what I'm even supposed to be looking for, but I'm giving it my best shot, as i'm fairly new to using PHP and MySQL databases. So i'll try to explain my situation best as possible.

1. I have a HTML table that has data imported from a MySQL database into it. I have three columns consisting of a name, state, and city. The first column, which consists of school names, has hyperlinks in each of the cells, which I intend to link to a separate page, specifically designed to give more information on that said school being clicked including information contained in the same MySQL table.

   2. The separate page that I have to create has to have a personal profile for that school's name, and I have to use the rest of the data in my MySQL database to fill in the fields.

Basically, this is what you would have to experience as a user.

1. You open and view this giant list of schools in a html table consisting of 3 columns, the school name, the city, and the state.
2. You see the name of a school you are interested in is hyperlinked to a separate page.
3. You click on the link of a school.
4. A page opens with the same name, city, and state from the same school thats clicked on, including more information thats stored in the same database table as the one being using for the the first page.

If anyone has any idea for me to go about creating this or any help at all, I would greatly appreciate it. I've thought of making an entire page for each name cell, but theres over 5,000 names of school in this database, and I have a gut feeling telling me that theres an easier way to do this.

Comment: May be this could help you : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928

Comment: an [a href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) column. That ref points to a php that displays the school info in all its glory